# Adding a specific Row of a Table to the number of tables In R with respect to the Table name

Tags: r, row, addition

I have number of tables which contain temperature variable.
Moreover I have a table which contain coordinates.
I want to assign a specific row of the coordinate table to the temperature tables. In other words as a result a new column will be created in each temperature table which contains a row of the coordinate table. Moreover, based on id of the coordinate table corresponding values of the table should be added to the relevant temperature table with respect to the table name.

```
Table1:Tab2:Tab3: Tab4:                       
-0.52|-0.93|-0.23|-0.32                           
-0.56|-0.33|-0.13|-0.37
-0.54|-0.13|-0.33|-0.64
-0.5 |-0.93|-0.53|-0.63
-0.54|-0.83|-0.63|-0.43
-0.56|-0.53|-0.38|-0.34
-0.62|-0.03|-0.13|-0.33

Coordinate:
id       E              N       
2     2579408.2431  1079721.1499
3     2579333.7158  1079729.1852
4     2579263.6502  1079770.1125
5     2579928.0358  1080028.4605
6     2579763.6471  1079868.9218
7     2579698.0756  1079767.9762
8     2579543.1019  1079640.6512

Results:
Table2:
Temperature  coordinate 
-0.52        2579408.2431  1079721.1499                    
-0.56        2579408.2431  1079721.1499   
-0.54        2579408.2431  1079721.1499
-0.5         2579408.2431  1079721.1499
-0.54        2579408.2431  1079721.1499
-0.56        2579408.2431  1079721.1499
-0.62        2579408.2431  1079721.1499
```

Comment: Assuming the coordinates are truly identical, consider `?merge`

Comment: @sebastian-c, How I can apply merge while I want to preform it automatically and filling all the rows with the same value.

Comment: You have 8 coordinates, but 4 temperature sets. Do they match up in order? Is there a reason for those extra 4 coordinates?

Comment: @sebastian-c, Those tables are just an example. I have almost 100 tables and 100 coordinates which should be matched base on Id and table name.

Comment: Yes, but an example should be minimal so as not to confuse the question. Are both your table columns and coordinate rows in the right order?

Comment: @sebastian-c, I cannot understand what do u mean by right order. I have tables from 2 to 100 and an other table which presents the relevant coordinates. The order of the coordinates are ascending.

Comment: I started this chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20116/discussion-between-ali-amidi-and-sebastian-c so we can discuss this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat <- read.table(text="Table1|Table2|Table3|Table4
-0.52|-0.93|-0.23|-0.32
-0.56|-0.33|-0.13|-0.37
-0.54|-0.13|-0.33|-0.64
-0.5 |-0.93|-0.53|-0.63
-0.54|-0.83|-0.63|-0.43
-0.56|-0.53|-0.38|-0.34
-0.62|-0.03|-0.13|-0.33", sep="|", header=T)

coord <- read.table(text="id       E              N       
2     2579408.2431  1079721.1499
3     2579333.7158  1079729.1852
4     2579263.6502  1079770.1125
5     2579928.0358  1080028.4605
6     2579763.6471  1079868.9218
7     2579698.0756  1079767.9762
8     2579543.1019  1079640.6512", header=T)
```

First, let's turn the column names into digits:

```
> names(dat) <- gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", names(dat))
```

Then stack the data and change the names:

```
> stacked <- stack(dat)
> names(stacked) <- c("Temperature, id")
```

Finally, we merge the data:

```
> merge(stacked, coord)
   id Temperature       E       N
1   2       -0.93 2579408 1079721
2   2       -0.33 2579408 1079721
3   2       -0.13 2579408 1079721
4   2       -0.93 2579408 1079721
5   2       -0.83 2579408 1079721
6   2       -0.53 2579408 1079721
7   2       -0.03 2579408 1079721
8   3       -0.23 2579334 1079729
9   3       -0.13 2579334 1079729
10  3       -0.33 2579334 1079729
11  3       -0.53 2579334 1079729
12  3       -0.63 2579334 1079729
13  3       -0.38 2579334 1079729
14  3       -0.13 2579334 1079729
15  4       -0.32 2579264 1079770
16  4       -0.37 2579264 1079770
17  4       -0.64 2579264 1079770
18  4       -0.63 2579264 1079770
19  4       -0.43 2579264 1079770
20  4       -0.34 2579264 1079770
21  4       -0.33 2579264 1079770
```